# If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d., integrable, nonnegative, then $\min(X_1,X_2)^2$ is integrable

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, variance

> Let $X_1$, $X_2$ be i.i.d., integrable, nonnegative real random variables, and $Y=\min(X_1,X_2)$. Show that $Y^2$ is integrable.

Does anyone have some hints or tips on how to show this?

Comment: Assuming $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d., one cannot have $X_1 \leq X_2$ almost surely unless $X_1$ is a constant almost surely.

Comment: Rewrote the question to eliminate some awkward formulations and the irrelevant hypothesis that $X_i^2$ is not integrable. Now, what is severely lacking is some input from the OP...

Comment: Try $0\le Y^2\le X_1X_2$ and use the independence to decompose the joint measure into the product of two marginal measures and then use Fubini.

Comment: Why was this question put on hold?? ther are NO additional informations to this problem. That's why I had such problems with it

Comment: Because the site is not made for dumping naked problems (as is explained in quite a few howtoask pages, I must add).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Since $Y^2 \leq X_1X_2$, we have $\mathbb{E}(Y^2) \leq \mathbb{E}(X_1X_2)=\mathbb{E}(X_1)\mathbb{E}(X_2) < +\infty$.

**Solution 2**

Let $g(t)=\mathbb{P}(X_1>t)$.

- Show that $\mathbb{E}(X_1)=\int_0^\infty g(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$.
- Show that $\mathbb{E}(Y^2)=\int_0^\infty 2tg(t)^2 \,\mathrm{d}t$.
- Show that when $t$ tends to $+\infty$, $g(t)=o(1/t)$. For instance, you could show that $xg(x) \leq 2\int_{x/2}^x g(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$ for any $x>0$.
- Show that $tg(t)^2=o(g(t))$.
- Conclude.

Edit : as pointed out by Did in the comments, we need another argument to conclude.

Edit 2 : I added two steps. This should work now.

Edit 3 : That was simpler than I thought. Thanks to D. Thomine.

Edit 4 : added Vim's solution since it is much simpler.

Comment: The step "Conclude" stays rather mysterious since $g(t)=o(1/t)$ does not imply that $tg(t)^2$ is integrable.

Comment: Oh you are right, I went too fast.

Comment: But $g(t)$ nonincreasing and integrable implies that $t g(t)^2$ is integrable. Indeed, $g(t) = O(1/t)$, so $t g(t)^2 = g(t) O(1)$.

Comment: Edited to include your comment, thanks.